# Store a object in firebase (app inventor 2)

Tags: android, firebase, indexing, firebase-realtime-database, app-inventor

I am writing a app from app inventor which is a notebook app

In the app there are two function

- View Note
- Add Note

In the **Add Note** function , I don't know how to upload an object to the firebase. And What I want is to create an id "1" "2" automatically

the object is something like this:

[image: the object is something like this]

What I am trying but not work (firebase won't split it in object but a json:

[image: What I am trying but not work (firebase won't split it in object but a json)]

Answer (score 0):

You should use push() method instead of "1", "2" etc. The push method generate a unique key for you actually it is exactly what you want. In your case there is a problem; if two user want to add a note at the same time at the same location whose note adding firstly? So, by using unique child keys, several clients can add children to the same location at the same time without worrying about write conflicts.

You can find id with getKey() method. [Look for usage of push() and getKey() methods.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

`{
  "notes": {
    "-KzY........": {
      "content": "This is my first note",
      "title": "Hello World!"
    },
    "-KzT........":: {
      "content": "This is my second note",
      "title": "Hello Firebase!"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: you have to make structure like this and have to set value under child a predefine key {
  "notes": {
    "-KzY........": {
          "user1":{
               "content": "This is my first note",
                "title": "Hello World!"
          },
          "user2": {
                "content": "This is my second note",
                 "title": "Hello Firebase!"
          } 
      }
   }
}

Comment: I am sorry that I am using App inventor with Scratch interface, I am going to get the object name "1" ... "12"... in order to assign a new name for the new object. If so , how can I get the current index / name for firebase object so that I could assign a new name